# Order by used by limit and offset is not returning result in expected order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I will try to answer my-own question, as I haven't found an exact solution on the internet.
I had a problem that my SQL query was returning a result which in some cases here missing some results. I will try to simplify the SQL query:

```
SELECT users.*, joined_table.sign_in_count as active_count 
FROM users ...
 JOIN ... 
WHERE ... 
ORDER BY active_count DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
```

Let's say if I query all the table, the result is:

```
[3,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,3,2,1,3,3,1,3] (so, five 1's , five 2's and five 3's)
```

When I would apply the `ORDER BY active_count DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5`
I would expect the result to be:

```
[2,2,2,2,2]
```

But I got results like:

```
[2,2,2,2,1] (it was missing fifth "2")
```

What I figured the problem was that for some reason the `ORDER BY` is not properly ordering the records before applying `LIMIT 5` and `OFFSET 5`, or at least not in a way that I was expecting. Maybe because of the `JOIN` or similar.

Comment: Please identify the DBMS you are using in the tags and in the question text.

Comment: In your example there are only 4 of each number, so the example was obviously mutilated when you simplified it. Have you read [this](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)?

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe I have updated the question, and thanks for the link. I did know what the problem is and using `where` instead of the offset is a possibility, but what I didn't know that there were actually some addons/gems that are utilizing that approach. Just as your post suggests - the limitation is that many resources use `limit` and `offset`, so in a way I am "stuck" with it for the time being, but good to know that those resources actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was adding to the `ORDER_BY` the `id` of the records as well. Even-though it slightly changed the ordering of the elements, but in a way it was consistent and there were no more unexpected missing elements.

So, the query that I used was:

```
SELECT users.*, joined_table.sign_in_count as active_count 
FROM users ...
 JOIN ... 
WHERE ... 
ORDER BY active_count DESC, id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
```